# Trigger insert in Oracle 10 g

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

This is my code for entering the data in bids table having item id as it's attribute. There is a table item that also has item id as it's attribute.I have done this trigger to enter the data only if the item is not sold.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIG FOR BIDS FOR EACH    ROW 
DECLARE
N_CNT NUMBER (1);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO N_CNT 
    FROM ITEM 
    WHERE ITEM_ID = :NEW.ITEM_ID 
      AND ITEM.STATUS='SOLD';

  IF N_CNT=1 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALREADY SOLD');
  END IF;
END;
```

It gives the error

> Pl/SQL :line 4:SQL statement ignored. ie BEGIN

Comment: `FOR BIDS` should something like `before insert on bids` part in the trigger declaration.

Comment: I have tried but no effect

Comment: what have you tried and what do you mean by "no effect"? show the code what you tried and the error if you received any

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIG BEFORE INSERT On BIDS FOR EACH    ROW 
DECLARE
N_CNT NUMBER (1);
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO N_CNT 
    FROM ITEM 
    WHERE ITEM_ID = :NEW.ITEM_ID 
      AND ITEM.STATUS='SOLD';

  IF N_CNT=1 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALREADY SOLD');
  END IF;
END;

Comment: and what do you mean by no effect?. It compiles perfectly when i tried.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TIG **before insert ON** BIDS FOR EACH    ROW

or after instead before

or update, delete instead insert